# Is it possible to swap two keys of an ordered dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, ordereddictionary

*Note: I am using python 3.8.2, so dictionaries are considered ordered*

I was creating a binary tree, and I used dictionaries to model the tree.
For example:
`{1:[2, 3], 2:[4, 5], 3:[], 4:[], 5:[]}`

In the example, the tree above would look like this:

```
         1
        / \
       2   3
      / \
     4   5
```

I was trying to simulate the ‘rising’ of some nodes, and keep the order of the dict as well.
I know that using `myDict[key1], myDict[key2] = myDict[key2], myDict[key1]` won’t work, as the places of the ***values*** change, not the keys.

I was also thinking of using `.popitem()` to remove the last value until I’m either at key1 or key2, and the keep going until I get to the other key, but this seems kinda hard. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Default dictionaries are ordered, based on insertion. An expensive option would be to create a new dictionary where you first add the right key order and then update the new one with the old values. Therefore your new values will be reversed but the rest will be ordered on insertion. Similar idea, convert dict to tuple or list, perform the swap and then recreate the dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionaries, although they now keep the insertion order, are not arbitrarily orderable otherwise. If you want really to use the dict order information to build your tree, I think the only reliable way would be to build a fresh dictionary, copying the contents of the original one, for each of these swap operations.

A more reasonable approach, if you want an arbitrarily ordered dictionary would be to inherit from `collections.abc.MutableMapping`and kep track of your data inside that object, using a dictionary and some other data structure, such as a list.

It may sound complicated, but it may be simpler than you think:

```py
from collections.abc import MutableMapping

class SuperOrdered(MutableMapping):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = {}
        self.order = []
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key not in self.data:
            self.order.append(key)
        self.data[key] = value
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.data[key]
    def __delitem__(self, key):
        del self.data[key]
        self.order.remove(key)
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)
    def __iter__(self):
        yield from iter(self.order)
    def replace_key(self, oldkey, newkey, value):
        if newkey in self.data:
            del self[newkey]
        position = self.order.index(oldkey)
        self.order[position] = newkey
        self.data[newkey] = value
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.__class__.__name__}({{{', '.join(repr(key) + ':' + repr(self.data[key]) for key in self)}}})"
```

And voilá - the mapping + the "replace_key" method should be enough for you to build your tree as you are thinking about it.

This is the class above in the interactive prompt:

```
In [18]: aa = SuperOrdered()                                                                                             

In [19]: aa["a"] = 1;aa["b"] = 2;aa["c"] = 3                                                                             

In [20]: aa                                                                                                              
Out[20]: SuperOrdered({'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3})

In [21]: aa.replace_key("a", "d", 4)                                                                                     

In [22]: aa                                                                                                              
Out[22]: SuperOrdered({'d':4, 'b':2, 'c':3})
```

Apart from this answer, and out of topic: if you want to check a tree implementation that I hope is "production ready", I've published one as part of my [extradict](https://github.com/jsbueno/extradict/blob/main/extradict/binary_tree_dict.py) package (pip installable).

**update**: One might also inherit from `collections.OrderedDict` and add a `replace_key` method there. That code would have to deal with OrderedDict internals, but it would not be hard.

*External links:
[Github modification](https://gist.github.com/jsbueno/9c215d44c2e6f0cc925385889046d6a9)*

Comment: The `__delitem__` method is `O[n]` - if you want it to be O[1], you can use the same class, but keep each value in `self.data` as a tuple, where the first element is its order. In all points you retrieve the values, return only the original value, and use the order information in ` __delitem__`. Even doing this, keep the `self.order` list so you can iterate in the desired order.

Comment: Here, I made a gist with the O(1) implementation: https://gist.github.com/jsbueno/9c215d44c2e6f0cc925385889046d6a9
(and if in time it shows to be useful, I might include it in the "extradict" package)

Comment: So what if I used `collections.OrderedDict` instead?

Comment: collections.OrderedDict has the same lack of features of current dictionaries. It is just there for backwards compatibility now. The problem being: they respect strict insertion order for keys, and the key order can't be controlled in any other way.

Comment: So do you think `collections.OrderedDict` might be removed from python one day?

Comment: It might nbe, but if so, that will take still several years. Python policy implies in first deprecating one thing, and only after on more release actually remove it - on minimal, that is when stuff is not simply marked as deprecated and remains in the stdlib. "OrderedDict" does not hurt anyone, and has the semantic advantage of making clear certain code relies on the dictionary being ordered.  If it is removed, it will not be sooner than 6 or 7 years from now.

Comment: I mean it's not like removing one whole *module*, so maybe around python 3.13 or 3.14?
(If there ever will be those versions)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230045/discussion-between-einsteinium-and-jsbueno).

Comment: (I reviewed OrderedDict source - it is a standalone pure python implementation on top of a regular dict, offers more functionality than the native ordered dicts in new Python, lik `from_keys` and `popitem` - therefore, no deprecation should occur. It misses a "replace_key" or equivalent, though.

Comment: Ah... Thank you! (I should’ve read the documentation)

Answer (score 1):

Since you only want to swap two keys, we could start off with the following code:

```py
>>> changedDict = {}
>>> for key, value in myDict.items():
...     if key not in (key1, key2):
...         changedDict[key] = value
```

And continue as follows:

```py
...     elif key == key1:
...         changedDict[key] = myDict[key2]
...     else:
...         changedDict[key] = myDict[key1]
```

Comment: @wim But can you think of any other way?

Comment: This is not all that bad  - as I mentioned in my  answer, is a simple and reliable way to do it, given the restrictions in dict ordering.